# Find which browser was used to log on via ADFS

Tags: dynamics-crm, adfs

We have Dynamics 365 on premise which uses ADFS/IFD to login. Is there a way to find out which browser was used by the user?

Comment: Are you seeing this option - Organization Insights? https://www.crmsoftwareblog.com/2017/06/dynamics_365_crm_organization_insights/

Answer (score 0):

Since you are on-prem, you should be able to look at your IIS logs to see which "useragent" is being used. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.applicationhost/sites/sitedefaults/logfile/

Comment: The later versions of ADFS don't run on IIS.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it is available for on-premise environments, but you could check the Admin Center

https://admin.powerplatform.microsoft.com

Here you can view these types of statistics, including Browsers

[image: Power Platform]